# Null return from controller

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, laravel

I have a service file where I'm running a stored procedure:

```
    function createCampaign($campaignName, $groupNumber){

    $stmt = \DB::connection('odbc')->getPdo()->prepare('CALL SCHEMA.INSERT_CAMPAIGN(?,?,?)');

    $stmt->bindValue(1,$campaignName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(2,$groupNumber, $groupNumber==0 ? PDO::PARAM_NULL : PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(3,$out2, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $stmt->execute();

    return $out2;

}
```

When I run this stored procedure, the third parameter is giving back `OUT_CAMPAIGN_ID` and the expected ID, so this works. I'm returning that output variable with `$out2`

My controller, which calls the previous function and also expects the return back:

```
 public function createCampaign(Request $request)
{
    $campaignName = $request->campaignName;
    $groupNumber = $request->groupNumber;

    $campaignService = new CampaignService();
    $createCampaign = $campaignService->createCampaign($campaignName, (int) $groupNumber);

    return Response::json(["OUT_CAMPAIGN_ID" => $createCampaign]);
}
```

However, when I console log `data.OUT_CAMPAIGN_ID` in my blade, or even console log `data` it just gives me `OUT_CAMPAIGN_ID:null`

Am I doing something wrong in the way I expect it back in the controller?

Stored procedure:

```
BEGIN

INSERT INTO SCHEMA.TABLE(NAME,NUMBER)
VALUES (IN_NAME, IN_NUMBER);

SET OUT_ID = IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL();

END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your stored procedure returns a value?  I think what you need to do is more like:

```
$stmt = \DB::connection('odbc')->getPdo()->prepare('CALL SCHEMA.INSERT_CAMPAIGN(?,?,?)');
$stmt->bindValue(1,$campaignName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(2,$groupNumber, $groupNumber==0 ? PDO::PARAM_NULL : PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $out2, PDO::PARAM_INT|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: That seems to error out with an invalid cursor state for the procedure

Comment: what is your stored procedure?

Comment: maybe try `$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Comment: just updated with the proc. It just sets that third param to the returned identity of the insert

Comment: Still invalid cursor state error. I don't think I should have to fetch though, I've done this previously by just returning the output value

Comment: Yeah I see.  In this case, I think you actually need to do `$stmt->bindParam(3, $out2, PDO::PARAM_INT|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT);`

Comment: Ah wow, worked like a charm!! Thanks so much, I didn't realize I needed to set the input output that way